# ASP.Net Control Button PostBack is causing redirection, when I don't want it to at all (print button)

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

here's how my scenario is created.

I click a button which produces a pdf via iTextSharp.

I then click 'Cancel' on the pop-up dialog.

I navigate to another page via hyperlink.

I then click the 'Back' button on IE8

I then click the button which produces the PDF, **then I'm redirected to the page I previously viewed (when I clicked the hyperlink).**  Which is not intended what so ever.

Here's some code that affects the Response object (code is within print_click event)

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ManageWorkforce.pdf");
Response.End();
```

Anyone have a theory why this is happening?

Comment: I've noticed similar behavior, so I decided to output files from a special handler instead of from a POST to the same page.

Comment: @Greg - Could you please give me more details on this "special handler" or do you have an article I could read to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Sure, something like this would probably work. http://www.developerfusion.com/code/5223/using-ashx-files-to-retrieve-db-images/  Basically you create a "Generic Handler" file (ashx), pass it an ID on the query string, and then write your output like you've shown here.

Comment: @Greg - Suppose I can't go down this path of Generic Handler(ashx) files.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: No, not really.  I was hoping someone else would answer the question. :/

Comment: What is it that you want to happen?  You want to view the PDF?

Comment: Please can you post the complete code behind the button click.

Comment: Why can't you go down the path of a Generic Handler?

Comment: Ah crap, I've moved away from this project now (different company)...  Sorry, I won't be able to provide anymore detail, nor would I be able to test any new proposals for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always done this with a generic handler like Greg mentioned. This is also nicer if you want to link to the file from other pages in the future, or save it as a favorite, send it to your friend, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
 Response.Clear();
 Response.ClearHeaders();
```

to clear any other content that may still be attached to the response content and headers?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put:

`<%@ OutputCache NoStore="true" %>`

on the `aspx` page.